# ItextSharp Error on trying to parse html for pdf conversion

Tags: c#, itext, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, xmlworker

I was using the ItextSharp module to convert the below listed html in to a pdf page.

```
        <div style="font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold;">
    mma<br>mmar</div><br> <br>
    <div style="font-size: 14pt;">Click to View Pricing
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr><td> <a href="http://www.mma.com/fci" style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;"> FCI</a>:</td> 
<td><a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-014" style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;"> 78211-014</a></td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-009" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-009</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-006" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-006</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-007" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-007</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-003" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-003</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-005" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-005</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-008"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-008</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-004" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-004</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-012" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-012</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-007LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-007LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-015LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-015LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-003LF"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-003LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-009LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration:
underline;">78211-009LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-005LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-005LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-010LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-010LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-006LF"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-006LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-014LF"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-014LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-004LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-004LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-012LF"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-012LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-008LF"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-008LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
<a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-011LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-011LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td><a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-013LF" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-013LF</td></tr><tr><td></td> <td><a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-010" style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-010</td></tr><tr><td></td>
<td><a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=78211-015"
 style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;">78211-015</td></tr><tr><td> 
<a href="http://www.mma.com/souriau" 
style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;"> Souriau</a>:</td>
 <td><a href="http://www.mma.com/access/?pn=24JR124-3" style="color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;"> 24JR124-3</a></td></tr></table></div>
```

C# code to generate the html above :

```
 var html = new StringBuilder(@"<div style=""font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold;"">Authorized Distributor</div><br> <br><div style=""font-size: 14pt;"">Click to View Pricing, Inventory, Delivery & Lifecycle Information:</div><br>");
            List<MfrBrandView> mfrBrands = MfrBrandView.Load(fileId);
            var uniquesuppliers = mfrBrands.GroupBy(t => new {t.Manufacturer,t.SupplierVirtualDirectory}).Select(g => g.First());
            html.Append("<div><table>");
            foreach (var uniquesupplier in uniquesuppliers)
            {
                var mfrPartNums =
                    mfrBrands.Where(t => t.ManufacturerId == uniquesupplier.ManufacturerId).Select(
                        t => t.ManufacturerPartNumber).ToList();
                html.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td> <a href=""http://www.mma.com/{0}"" style=""color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;""> {1}</a>:</td> <td><a href=""http://www.mma.com/access/?pn={2}"" style=""color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;""> {2}</a></td></tr>", uniquesupplier.SupplierVirtualDirectory, uniquesupplier.MouserizationLabel, mfrPartNums[0]);

                for (int i = 1; i < mfrPartNums.Count(); i++)
                {
                    html.AppendFormat(
                        @"<tr><td></td> <td><a href=""http://www.mma.com/access/?pn={0}"" style=""color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;"">{0}</td></tr>",
                        mfrPartNums[i]);
                }
            }
            html.Append("</table></div>");
            return html.ToString();
```

Code to generate the page after html is formed:

```
PdfWriter writer = null;
            PdfDocument doc = null;
            //PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
           // reader.Info["Title"]

            try
            {
                doc = new PdfDocument();
                doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, content);
                writer.CloseStream = false;
                doc.Open();
                doc.NewPage();

                foreach (IElement element in iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), null))
                {
                    doc.Add(element);
                }
            }
```

below is where i get an exception saying ***"Unable to cast object of type*** ***'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'***."
**`iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), null)`**

Is there something wrong with the html I'm trying to parse? Is there a better way of doing this? 
Thanks much in advance for your help. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the C# code? You are trying make a Cell a Paragraph. Just one level too high.

Comment: Well..I'd guess that's the ItextSharp Parser that is trying to do so. I dont know if certain html elements are not allowed while trying to convert html to PDF using Itextsharp

Comment: Itextsharp doesnt like that I put my <a> tags inside the <td> tags. Looks like that is  the issue.

Comment: yes....but not the way i exactly envisioned it.I had to put every <a> tag in a <div>. And had to make some compromises in terms of how I wanted my formatting on the page, because I couldn't arrange all the <a> tags in a table as required.

Comment: Better switch to iText7 and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57251780/14784590

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`HTMLWorker' [has been deprecated](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iText-PDF-using-HTML-Worker-issue-td4655474.html) in favor of [XMLWorker](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml). Here is a working example tested with a snippet of HTML like you used above:

```
StringReader html = new StringReader(@"
<div style='font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold;'>
Mouser Electronics <br />Authorized Distributor</div><br /> <br />
<div style='font-size: 14pt;'>Click to View Pricing, Inventory, Delivery & Lifecycle Information:
</div>
<br />
<div>
<table>
<tr><td></td><td>
<a href='http://www.mouser.com/access/?pn=78211-009' 
style='color: Blue; font-size: 10pt; text-decoration: underline;'>78211-009</a></td></tr>
</table></div>    
");      
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
    writer, document, html
  );
}
```

When using `XMLWorker` you need to use well-formed HTML - it's an XML parser, after all. The sample `HTML` from your question above doesn't have closing `<a>` or `<br>` tags. A `HTML` parser like  [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) will fix those problems, and turn this:

```
<div><img src='a.gif'><br><hr></div>
```

into this:

```
<div><img src='a.gif' /><br /><hr /></div>
```

with only a few lines of code:

```
var hDocument = new HtmlDocument()
{
    OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true,
    OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
};
hDocument.LoadHtml("<div><img src='a.gif'><br><hr></div>");
var closedTags  = hDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
```

`XMLWorker` is [available as a nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/), or [as a separate download at sourceforge](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases/tag/5.5.9).

**See [here for more advanced usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594030) of `XMLWorker`**.

Comment: Thanks ... That was a nice answer! We do not want to change from using the ITextsharp right now. Too far in to the project to do that.

Comment: is there an efficient workaround for this? I was doing lines and lines of html for doing this...basically putting all the 'links' in div tags.This changes the originally planned formatting of the files.

Comment: `XMLWorker` is a separate download, but it **IS** used with iTextSharp. So you can use your original formatting (`<table>` tags) instead of wrapping the hyperlinks in `<div>` tags as in the sample code provided above. I'm not sure what you mean by using an efficient workaround - if you take a look at the first link I quoted above from the iText mailing list, it mentions that somewhere late in the 4.xx branch or in the 5.xx branch hyperlinks in table cells became broken, and that the iText development team has no plans to do further development on `HTMLWorker`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you! I thought you were talking about a completely different tool. I get what you're saying.

Comment: This code successfully worked but Turkish characters are not showing at PDF document. How to set encoding for this code?

Comment: Both iTextSharp and iTextSharp XML Worker are also available as NuGet pacages https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/

Comment: Nice and complete answer, especially with the HtmlAgilityPack addition, you got my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
    &lt;a href="http://www.abcd.com"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

Here we are replacing < with `&lt`; and > with `&gt`; so my  becomes `&lt;a&gt;` and     becomes   `&lt;/a&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step what you need to do

1-  Install itext sharp and  XMLWorker from Itextsharp   from  nuget

2-Then put ur design in html(here Invoice.html) with inline CSS

3-Make sure all tag are ended properly like breakpoint or td(here I got error earlier)

4-here image wouldn't show locally so without wasting time I uploaded image in server and gave server Path to access Image.U can research more to run it locally.

```
Document doc = new Document();

PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(4);

PdfWriter writer= PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/T13.pdf"), FileMode.Create));                 

doc.Open();

string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/invoice.html"));

StringReader sr = new StringReader(contents);


XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, sr);  

doc.Close();
```