# How I can use a html file with styles for creat a pdf file with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, pdf, itext

Hi I want to create a pdf in my **ASP.NET** Application and for this I use `iTextSharp`. My idea is it to create a pdf out of a HTML file. I want that if I click on a `Button` I read a HTML file with a background-image and much styles.

My Application must do..

1. Read a HTML file from the Folder `App.Data`. (using System.IO)
2. Create a PDF out of this HTML file with this styles! (`using iTextSharp.text;`
   `using iTextSharp.text.pdf;`)
   3.send the PDF file as email. (using System.Net.Mail;using System.Net.Mime;)

I try to create a PDF and if work but if I use styles in my HTML file it doesn't show the styles :(

here is my code:

```
string html;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/mail.html"), System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd(); //here i read the html file to this string
    HTMLtoPdf(html);
}

private void HTMLtoPdf(string HTML) 
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();
    HTMLWorker hw = new HTMLWorker(doc);
    hw.Parse(new StringReader(HTML));
    doc.Close();

    ShowPdf("test.pdf");
}

private void ShowPdf(string s)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + s);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(s);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Clear();
}
```

For example my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html><head>

</head><body styles="background-color:#E0E0E0; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; font-size:120%;">

<div>
    Test
</div>

</body></html>
```

In this Example I use background color but it don't work :( I get only the HTML text : test without styles.

Comment: it will be style not styles

Comment: yes a small error but the background color don't work

Comment: Use Style tag within body, not along with it...may be it will work, give it a try...

Comment: string html = "<html><head></head><body><div style='background-color:#E0E0E0;'>Test</div></body></html>"; ?

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113425/itextsharp-error-on-trying-to-parse-html-for-pdf-conversion

Answer (score 0):

You've spelled "style" wrong.

```
<body styles="background-color:#E0E0E0;
```

It Should be

```
<body style="background-color:#E0E0E0;
```

Comment: I have this same problem, if you got answer please post me.

Answer (score 0):

you should use bgcolor here instead of background-color