# 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

While trying to create HTML to Pdf using itextsharp getting *Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.* exception.Here is the piece of code

```
string FilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/tenantStatement-print.html");
        StreamReader mstrFileStreamReader = new StreamReader(FilePath);

        string fileContents = mstrFileStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        mstrFileStreamReader.Close();

        String htmlText = fileContents;

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\DocumentEngine\\tempDocs\\") + "\\outfile.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
        hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
        document.Close();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=outfile.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\DocumentEngine\\tempDocs\\") + "\\outfile.pdf");
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
```

Comment: Please understand that `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned. You should use XML Worker instead: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker

Comment: possible duplicate of [ItextSharp Error on trying to parse html for pdf conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113425/itextsharp-error-on-trying-to-parse-html-for-pdf-conversion)